# System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection does not contain a definition for 'MapHubs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I follow sample from SignalR wiki page and here is my `Global.asax` :

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

But I'm getting:

'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHubs' and no extension method 'MapHubs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \Global.asax    11

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maphubs is an extension method to RouteCollection class in SignalR library. You would need to include SignalR references to call MapHubs.

Source:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb/SignalRRouteExtensions.cs

Comment: Ah thank you. But with correction - I need Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll , not Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll only

Comment: Just to add information for those hoping to use OWIN, simply add `app.MapSignalR();` to your `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` function inside your `Startup.Auth.cs` class. Make sure you have the most current version of SignalR (2.0.2, at time of writing)  added from NuGet.